# Gmock matcher to match against type

Tags: c++, unit-testing, matcher, googlemock

In gmock is there anyway to match against a type rather than value? The class is something like:

```
struct Blob {
    template<class T> bool is(); // if blob holds data of type T
    template<class T> T get(); // get data as type T
}
```

My matcher looks like this:

```
MATCHER_P(BlobIs, T, "") {
    return arg->is<T>();
}
```

But the build failed with:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

Comment: Did you add a template<class T> ? Also, shouldn't your matcher have a name ? Right now it is an empty string I believe

Comment: MATCHER_P is a macro, the string is not name, it's a description.

Comment: Did you tried something like `return arg->is<decltype(T)>();`? Passing to matcher value of type T, rather than just type.

Comment: T does not have default constructor, so i didn't try that, because i just want to have a matcher to assert on types.

Comment: "T does not have default constructor" - it doesn't matter you can pass pointer, e.g. `static_cast<T*>(nullptr)` and then get type of pointer. You can't pass just "type" where "value" is expected. You either need to implement your custom matcher without using macros, i.e. do something similar what `MATCHER_P()` does, or find some wrokaround.

Comment: exactly i was asking how to implement with MATCHER_P, i don't want to pass a value here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use wildcard matchers `A<type>` and `An<type>` ([documentation](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html#wildcard)):

```
EXPECT_CALL(foo, Describe(A<const char*>()))
    .InSequence(s2)
    .WillOnce(Return("dummy"));
```

Comment: Link seems to be broken in the answer, but you can read about it here now: http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html#wildcard

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass type as parameter to any function - including those generated by `MATCHER_P` macro.

But you can pass lambda(function object) that will use correct type.

Like here:

```
MATCHER_P(BlobIsImpl, isForForType, "") {
    return isForType(arg);
}
```

With the following function template - you will achieve the desired goal:

```
template <typename T>
auto BlobIs()
{
     auto isForType = [](Blob& arg) -> bool 
     { 
         return arg->template is<T>();
     };
     return BlobIsImpl(isForType); 
}
```

Use like this:  `BlobIs<SomeType>()`

2 more issues:

1. You have to use `template` keyword to specify that `is` is a function template. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)
2. You should define `is` as const function.